# Wordpress: Tax query doesn't sort according to custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom field that name "tour_date". The Tour date field keeps dates as timestamps. I want it to be sorted according to the tour date field as a result of the search. However, the query I wrote does not work properly, the results do not come sequentially. My codes are as follows.

```
?php

    
    if(isset($_GET['keyword']) && !empty($_GET['keyword']))
    {  
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'tours',
            'post_title_like'     => $_GET['keyword'],
            'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
            'meta_key'=> 'tour_date', 
            'order' => 'ASC', 
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'tourtag',
                    'field'    => 'name',
                    'terms'    => $_GET['keyword']
                ),
            ),
        );       
    }

    query_posts($args);

?>
```

Here is my sql query result

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( 0 = 1 ) AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'tour_date' ) AND ((wp_posts.post_type = 'tours' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled')))OR (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%iran%' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'tour' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC LIMIT 0, 10Array ( [post_type] => tours [post_title_like] => iran [orderby] => meta_value_num [meta_key] => tour_date [order] => ASC [tax_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [taxonomy] => tourtag [field] => name [terms] => iran ) ) ) 1
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but why are you using both `new WP_Query` and `query_posts`?

Comment: it was related to print my query, it must be commented. i edited.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are talking about an actual numeric Unix timestamp value here, yes?

Comment: my my custom field type is date (Ymd) like 20220401